# Duplicate definitions in Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core and Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin

Tags: signalr, owin

I have a web application using SignalR and Owin. Beside others, I am using the NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core: 2.2.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin: 1.2.2
- Microsoft.Owin: 3.0.1
- Owin: 1.0

When I start the Owin application using OwinHost.exe, I always see the following outut after the first request

> Exception thrown while getting types from 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin, Version=1.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.', Exception=System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>           at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
>           at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
>           at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolverTracer.GetTypesAndTrace(Assembly
>   assembly)

For seeing the mentioned LoaderExceptions property, I added to my startup code:

```
try
{
  Assembly a = Assembly.Load("Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin");
  var types = a.GetTypes(); 
}
catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)           
{
  foreach (var e2 in e.LoaderExceptions)
    Console.WriteLine(e2);          
}
```

This produced the additional output:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.IWebSocketRequest' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. 
>   System.TypeLoadException: Type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.DefaultWebSocketHandler' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin, Version=1.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface.

The next step was to instantiate `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.DefaultWebSocketHandler` manually:

```
var handler = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.DefaultWebSocketHandler();
```

Unfortunately, this created a compile error:

> The type 'DefaultWebSocketHandler' exists in both 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin, Version=1.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

In the Object Browser, I can see that this is right. But I do not know, how I can get rid of the error.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is quite easy: I just had to remove Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.

I came to this solution after inspecting the two assemblies with ILSpy. I found the `OwinExtensions` from `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin` in `ObsoleteOwinExtensions` from `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core`. Moreover, I were using already the `OwinExtensions` from `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core`.

Another hint could have been the outdated version of `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin`...